# Making dynamic text movable?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this DIY designer where a user can put text on a board. The problem is it cant be moved. I can do draggable movieclips but not dynamic text. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your dynamic text is going into something like a label or an Flex TextArea or TextInput or something.  You should just be able to move the container itself by setting the `x` and `y` properties.  TextInputs have opaque backgrounds, but it sounds like you should probably be using a Flex TextArea or something similar anyway.

Comment: The dynamic text is from an input text field that is for inputting text from the user. So its kinda tricky.